# DBmail not receiving mail

Tags: mysql, email, postfix, email-server, imap

I setup DBmail (MySQL) with Postfix and stunnel, but I still can't receive mail. I can login to the server though. But when I send a mail to a user that I created with dbmail-user:

```
dbmail-users -a user -p crypt -w psword
dbmail-users -c user -s user@domain.com
```

I don't receive anything. And the logs (mail, mail.log, mail.err, dbmail/dbmail.log) are empty! What can I do now?

P.S. It's an IMAP server.

Answer (score 1):

If your mail.log is empty it means that you Postfix is not receiving emails for that user. You should start from there.

Are the MX records for your domain pointing to the machine where Postfix is?